# how to have images be shown for a certain amount of time if a buttons pressed

Tags: java, animation, javafx

So, i'm working on a jumping animation and it works fine but i'm trying to get it so an image will be shown for a certain amount of time (time= time spent in the air) if a button is pressed but return to the original image once the sprite reaches the ground. I've researched quite a lot but i'm yet to find a suitable answer. However i'm thinking of changing the imageview if a certain button is pressed but i'm not sure if this would work.

my code

```
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480, Color.ALICEBLUE);

    Image imgninja = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ninja_sprite.png"));
    Image tempground = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ground.png"));
    Image tempground2 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ground.png"));
    final Image test = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myninja_1.png"));
    final Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
    r.setX(rectx);
    r.setY(recty);
    r.setWidth(50);
    r.setHeight(100);
    r.setArcWidth(20);
    r.setArcHeight(20);

    Button button = new Button();
    iview = new ImageView(imgninja);
    iview.setLayoutX(ninjax);
    iview.setLayoutY(ninjay);
    iview2 = new ImageView(tempground);
    iview2.setLayoutX(backgroundx);
    iview2.setLayoutY(backgroundy);
    iview3 = new ImageView(tempground2);
    iview3.setLayoutX(555);
    iview3.setLayoutY(backgroundy);
    iview4 = new ImageView(test);
    iview4.setLayoutX(aix);
    iview4.setLayoutY(aiy);


    root.getChildren().addAll(iview2, iview3, button, iview, r,iview4);
    primaryStage.setTitle("A basic window");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    button.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {

                ninjax = ninjax - 10;
                iview.setLayoutX(ninjax);
            }

            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {

                if (ninjay > 365) {
                    jumpforce = -16;

                }
                iview.setLayoutY(ninjay);

            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {


                ninjax = ninjax + 10;

                iview.setLayoutY(ninjax);

            }

        }

    });

    new AnimationTimer() {


        @Override

        public void handle(long now) {

            if (iview.getBoundsInParent().intersects(iview2.getBoundsInParent())) {

                groundforce = -gravity;

            } else {
                groundforce = 0;

            }

            if (jumpforce < 0) {

                ninjay = ninjay - (-gravity) + jumpforce + groundforce;
                ninjax = ninjax + 3;

                jumpforce = jumpforce + 1;

            } else if (ninjay < 365) {
                ninjay = ninjay - (gravity) + jumpforce + groundforce;

                ninjax = ninjax + 3;

            }

            iview.setLayoutY(ninjay);
            iview.setLayoutX(ninjax);

        }

    }.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can do this with a `PauseTransition`:

```
Duration delay = ... ;
PauseTransition timer = new PauseTransition(delay);
timer.setOnFinished(evt -> undoWhatIDidToUI());
doSomethingToUI();
timer.play();
```

So, if I understand you,

```
Duration delay = ... ; // time for a jump
PauseTransition jumpTimer = new PauseTransition(delay);
jumpTimer.setOnFinished(evt -> iview.setImage(imgninja));
iview.setImage(jumpingImage);
jumpTimer.play();
```

It might be easier though to just detect if you are currently jumping in the animation timer, and call `setImage(...)` with the appropriate image depending on whether you are jumping or not. (Calling `setImage(...)` with the same image as is currently used is basically a no-op, so there should be no performance issues doing that.) This would, I think, just look like:

```
@Override
public void handle(long now) {

    // existing code...

    if (jumpforce < 0) {
        iview.setImage(jumpingImage);
    } else {
        iview.setImage(imgninja);
    }

    // ...
}
```